# Building a colony on an ice crust

Tags: science-based, space-colonization

Stories like The Expanse sometimes depict building colonies places like Ganymede.  There's good reason to do so, but one thing has always nagged at me; how would the icy crust respond?  Ganymede, Callisto and the like are all so cold that the ice in the surface is a different type of ice crystal, one hard as rock.  Not only would losing heat to the surface be a big energy drain, but if the ice warms up enough, its crystalline structure would change, possibly to the point of cracking, wouldn't it?

How much insulation would you need to build on that without causing issues?  Would a typical home's insulation thickness of aerogel do the trick, or would the layer need to be quite beefy?  This is not just important to note for a dome colony on the surface, but varied tunnels will need this too.

Maybe I'm overthinking this, but I've never seen this addressed before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Buildings on Ganymede would not be like buildings on Earth.**

The difference is that Earth has an atmosphere.  That fact leads to 2 differences relevant to building.

- Weather.  Earth buildings must resist being blown away.  That is not an issue on Ganymede.  A building on Ganymede does not need to be firmly anchored to substrate in the way an Earth building must.
- Heat loss.  There are 3 main methods of heat transfer: [convection, conduction and radiation](https://www.machinedesign.com/learning-resources/whats-the-difference-between/document/21834474/whats-the-difference-between-conduction-convection-and-radiation).

Convection is transfer of heat via movement of heated gases.  That is a huge issue on Earth because there is always a huge mass of gas outside trying to equilibrate in temperature with the building.  On Ganymede there is not.  Outside, there is nowhere for heat to go.

Conduction is direct transfer between apposing solids - like a frying pan and a egg.  Conduction is relevant on Ganymede but only where the building touches the ice.  If it barely touches and only thru thermally nonconductive supports, conduction losses are minimal.

Radiation.  Hot things radiate heat.  Compared to the above 2, infrared radiation into space would be minimal.  You could insulate the building.  You have access to the best insulator there is: vacuum.

Ganymede buildings would sit on thermally nonconductive stilts to minimize contact with the ice.  The stilts could be changed out if the ice moved or otherwise shifted around them.  I like the idea of watching for stilt shifts with spirit levels attached to the building frame.  You could jack up the building, put some new stilts underneath or reposition old ones, and settle it back down.

Ganymede buildings would be insulated against radiant losses by an insulating layer of vacuum between outer shell and building outside.  Another way to affect radiant loss is to maximize radiant gains.  Ganymede buildings would be matte black.

Comment: Re stilts, rather than replacing them, you would just need to have jack screws.  If you want high tech, have motors and level sensors, and the building is automatically levelled until the jacks reach the extento of their travel.

Comment: @jamesqf - I like that very much!  Good grist for the mill as regards story telling.  The residents will sometimes feel icequakes, then the reassuring murmur of the robojacks as they compensate for shift.

Comment: Huh, I hadn't considered the idea that a Ganymede colony wouldn't need to be anchored firmly, but that makes sense.  No wind or storms means nothing short of deliberate action or an icequake would budge it.  Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

For any thermal insulation at equilibrium, if you plot the temperature vs the depth of the insulation you will see that the closer to the outside, the closer is the temperature to the outside temperature and vice versa, the close to the inside, the closer the temperature to the inside temperature.

This is why if you wear a coat outside when it's snowing, you will see that snow will deposit on it and won't melt until you go inside.

What the insulation really does is reducing the heat flow from the hot environment to the cold environment. Since we are talking about temperatures well below those encountered on Earth, also the insulation will be nothing that we have seen on Earth: some 10 cms of rock-wool or PS on a frozen planet would be like wearing a T-shirt outside the Overlook Hotel when Jack is visiting the maze for the last time.

The real structure of the insulation depends on a lot of factors, including properties of the available materials, available heat source, economic and engineering constrains.

Comment: Hmm, so not thin as a home's insulation, but not necessarily stupidly thick based on how this works.  I'm remembering pictures of thin aerogel between a flower and a blowtorch.

Comment: @SamD.Jones, don't confuse a lab stunt for the sake of the journalists with the real life application where several demands have to be satisfied

Comment: Hmm, true.  Aerogel does seem to be quite the insulator though.  Maybe not to the extent of the previously mentioned example, but still good.

Answer (score 2):

Ganymede is 150km of ice, then 100km of salt water, the more ice, then rock, then a core of liquid iron. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganymede_(moon)

This isn't a dead world that we could inadvertently heat up. It's molten iron that has a nice insulting blanket consisting of more water than we have of Earth, frozen under a vertical stack of 75 Antarcticas.

[image]

The ice under the [Australian Antarctic research station is 2.16km](https://www.antarctica.gov.au/about-antarctica/ice-and-atmosphere/sea-ice/ice-sheet/), and our settlement hasn't melted its way through that. A 150km ice sheet wouldn't fail because of lost heat from the settlement.

Your insulation needs to be thick enough to optimise your heating - a design similar to what we're doing in Antarctica will reduce power usage and minimise the heat lost into the ice.

Comment: I never suggested the ice would melt.  That would be ridiculous.  The question is, would there be any ill effects of the ice warming up enough to change crystalline form and how insulated would a habitable structure need to be in the presence of ice colder than anything Antarctica ever experiences.

Comment: NOT similar to Antarctica.  Antarctica has an atmosphere. Ganymede doesn't, so the only losses are by radiation and conduction to the ground.  OTOH, air leaks aren't that big a deal in Antarctica :-)